# How can I deploy my next js app to iis server?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, next.js

I have an IIS Server and a Next JS app which is mosty SSR. The problem is that I'm connected through a VPN and it was very easy to deploy a react-create-app, just moving the build folder and than all was working. Now it does not work the same and I do not find enough documentation for my problem.

Comment: Can share what you have tried so far? What is working and what not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an easy way like react-create-app, you can use NextJS export function which doesn't have server side. Then you can just run `next export` and upload your `next` build folder to your server.

If you insist to have SSR on your NextJS app, then the way you upload your app might be more difficult than just a upload your build folder. Because your app now has a server side that you need to run in your IIS server.

1. The easiest way to run Next SSR app on your server is by copying the whole root folder of your app to the server and run the production mode.
2. Other than that is by using containerization, so you build your app's image and push to the repo, then your IIS server will get this image and run it in the container.